# Numbering in SVJour document class

Tags: numbering, sv-classes

I am using the SVJour document class for a paper I am currently writing.  The default numbering scheme is as follows:

```
Theorem 1
Corollary 1
Theorem 2
Proposition 1
Example 1
etc.
```

Which is completely independent of the chapter or section.  I want to have:

```
Section 1
Proposition 1.1
Theorem 1.2
Proposition 1.3
etc.
Section 2
Proposition 2.1
Example 2.2 
etc.
```

If I put

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{exm}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{deff}[thm]{Definition}
```

in the preamble then I almost get what I want but instead there is no dot, i.e.,

```
Section 1
Proposition 11
Theorem 12
Proposition 13
etc.
Section 2
Proposition 21
Example 22 
etc.
```

Anyone know how to fix this?  The SVJour user guide uses `\spnewtheorem` instead of `\newtheorem` (which I've never seen before) but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 4):

The class offers you several class options to control numbering:

[image]

So you are interested in the class options `numbook` or `envcountsect`, and `envcountsame` (`envcountreset` is activated by default).

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[stropt,envcountsect,envcountsame]{svjour}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{theorem}
test
\end{theorem}
\begin{proposition}
test
\end{proposition}
\section{Test section two}
\begin{theorem}
test
\end{theorem}
\begin{proposition}
test
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The option ' envcountsame ' cause cleveref displays "Theroem" for all predefined theorem-like environments in svjour3. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @丢人素学姐 I was wondering the same thing, so I took the liberty of turning this into a separate question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595401/). Please let us know if you found a solution!